# "Disable touchpad while typing" duration can't be lower than 1s?

Tags: xubuntu, touchpad, xfce

The slider start from 0.1s to 4s with 0.1s increment, but if I set it to 0.9s or lower, then it doesn't have any effect, at all, I can still type while moving and click and etc.

It is only working when the slider is on 1s at minimum. The problem is, 1 second is way too long.

If this is the GUI interface bug (which I think it is), is there a command line option to set it up manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget about the buggy XFCE touchpad settings dialog, just run the following line in terminal:

```
syndaemon -i 0.5 -t -K -d
```